# Twilio Fax Change the font on outbound faxes

Tags: twilio

I am using Twilio Programmable Fax.  I create a PDF using a specific font and Size.  When that pdf is sent to twilio for faxing the font is replaced is a different one. Is there any way to set the font that will be used on the outgoing fax?.  The only parameter i see is Quality -  which changes only the resolution not the font of the text.

Comment: Please add links and code samples

Answer (score 0):

This issue is more around the PDF and how fonts are handled. See the link below.

> A font can be embedded only if it contains a setting by the font
> vendor that permits it to be embedded. Embedding prevents font
> substitution when readers view or print the file, and ensures that
> readers see the text in its original font

[Font embedding and substitution](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-fonts.html#font_embedding_and_substitution)